# Браузер не запоминает Last-Modified!

Tags: php, кэширование

Пытаюсь отдать браузеру заголовок Last-Modified. Однако браузер помнит его только пока открыт. Стоит только закрыть и перезапустить браузер, и он уже не возвращает заголовок If-Modified-Since. Вопрос: почему так и как заставить браузер помнить Last-Modified после перезапуска? 
Пробывал на Хроме и Мозиле.

Набросал небольшой код для иллюстрации проблемы:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) or isset($_ENV['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
{
    echo 'Сервер принял от пользователя заголовок "If-Modified-Since" со значением "'.$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'].'" и подтвердил его.';
}
else
{
    header('Last-Modified: Mon, 18 Oct 2010 14:15:00 GMT');
    echo 'Заголовок "Last-Modified" был отправлен пользователю.';
}
```

То есть если открыть страницу с этим кодом, а потом закрыть браузер, запустить его снова и вновь обратиться к этой странице, то браузер не возвращает If-Modified-Since.

PS: прошу тапками не кидаться

Comment: Что-то вот такое: `Для всех кешируемых ресурсов нужно обязательно указывать один заголовок из пары Expires и Cache-Control max-age, а также один заголовок из пары Last-Modified и ETag. Использовать и Expires, и Cache-Control: max-age излишне, как и указывать Last-Modified и ETag одновременно.` и `Last-Modified – "слабый" заголовок, так как браузер применяет эвристические алгоритмы, чтобы определить, запрашивать ли элемент из кеша.`

Comment: А почему браузер должен помнить ?и вообще браузеру по барабану этот заголовок.При каждом обращении к данной странице какой заголовок выставишь такой и будет .Этот заголовок нужен индекссирующим ботам

Comment: Ну так вообще полезный заголовок, можно тяжелый дизайн хранить на клиенте, да и пометить клиента им можно.

Answer (score 1):

В общем ларчик просто открывался. Вместе с Last-Modified необходимо отправлять заголовок Cache-Control: must-revalidate 
Это заставит браузер каждый раз отправлять запрос для валидации контента.